# Programmatically identify PHP and ASP include dependencies

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, iis

I am trying to automate the cleanup of legacy/heritage code and I can identify current resources in use from IIS logs but server side pages like .ASP and .PHP have include chains which I would like to be able to identify via code (C#)

In order to narrow the question down as it was too broad ...

- OS - Windows 10
- Web Server - IIS
- Preferred language - C#
- Example - any IIS served website

I have code that reads IIS log files where I have identified all static served resources including the initial .ASP or .PHP pages.

I required some accompanying C# code to also detail any .ASP or .PHP included files that were processed on the server and therefore do not appear in the IIS logs.

As it happens I have found the solution and provided an answer below.

I hope this is enough detail to take this off 'On Hold'

Comment: Php allows user mappings of class names to file paths (autoloading) via spl_autoload_register in any which way.  Otherwise I'd say look for include/require(_once) lines.

Comment: Off-topic : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Won't cover everything, but recent last access file times?

Comment: To make this question more on topic, give an example of code/processes you've tried so far, expected outcomes and what works and doesn't for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Progrock for pointing me to checking last accessed time for files in target folder.  This is what I had to do.

Ensure capturing last accessed time is being set by Windows (see [Directory.GetFiles keeping the last access time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253437/directory-getfiles-keeping-the-last-access-time))

```
Process.Start("fsutil", "behavior set disablelastaccess 0").WaitForExit();
```

Also need to restart IIS to stop any cached in memory files

```
Process.Start("IISRESET").WaitForExit();
```

A refresh on FileInfo needs to be performed to ensure you get the correct last accessed time (see [How can System.IO.FileSystemInfo.Refresh be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414564/how-can-system-io-filesysteminfo-refresh-be-used)).

This resulted in the following code ...

```
var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
Process.Start("fsutil", "behavior set disablelastaccess 0").WaitForExit();
Process.Start("IISRESET").WaitForExit();
//do work that will access folder. i.e. access IIS web pages
var files = Directory.GetFiles(iisPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
files = files.Where(x =>
{
  var fileInfo = new FileInfo(x);
  fileInfo.Refresh();
  return fileInfo.LastAccessTimeUtc >= start;
}).ToList();
```

I can use this list of files to identify all .ASP and .PHP and any other files that were accessed via the IIS server on page requests.